# TypeError: test02_logout() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'email' and 'password'

Tags: python, python-decorators, ddt

`login_data1.json` file

```
{
    "Admin1" : {
        "email": "some1@nomail.com",
        "password": "123"
    },
    "Admin2" : {
        "email": "some2@nomail.com",
        "password": "1234"
    }
}
```

`testdata.py` file

`valid_login_json_file = "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/apautomationpython/src/main/automation/web/utilities/data_files/login_data1.json"`

`test_home_page.py` file

```
import unittest
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from ddt import data, file_data, unpack
from src.main.automation.web.utilities.test_data import TestData
from src.main.automation.web.Pages.loginPage import LoginPage


class Home(unittest.TestCase):

    def login(self, email, password):
        # instantiate an object of LoginPage class.
        login = LoginPage(self.driver)
        # Enter valid login credentials
        login.login(email, password)
        time.sleep(4)


    # verify logout
    @file_data(TestData.valid_login_json_file)
    @unpack
    def test02_logout(self, email, password):
        # login with valid credentials
        self.login(email, password)
```

Running code throws
`TypeError: test02_logout() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'email' and 'password'`
I am not getting where I am doing wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 4):

In order to use ddt, the `TestCase` subclass must be annotated with `@ddt`:

```
...
@ddt
class Home(unittest.TestCase):
    ...
```